# Can't read types from assembly using Entity Framework Core 5.0

Tags: c#, .net-core, reflection, entity-framework-core

I am trying to read the types out of an assembly that contains Entity Framework Core, but I am getting this error:

> Could not load file or assembly '..file path..\TestRoslyn\Database\bin\Debug\net5.0\Database.dll'. The system cannot find the file specified.

The code I am using to read the types is pretty simple:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Build.Locator;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild;

namespace TestRoslyn
{
    class Program
    {
        static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            if (!MSBuildLocator.IsRegistered) 
                 MSBuildLocator.RegisterDefaults();

            using var w = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();

            // Substitute your file location
            var basePath = @"C:\Users\username\source\repos\";
            var slnFile = @$"{basePath}TestRoslyn\TestRoslyn.sln";
            var sln = await w.OpenSolutionAsync(slnFile);

            foreach (var p in sln.Projects)
            {
                var asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(p.OutputFilePath);
                foreach(var t in asm.GetTypes())
                    Console.WriteLine($"{p.OutputFilePath}\t{t.FullName}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works as is. However, when I add a simple project to the solution that references nuget package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` (5.0) with one file:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Database
{
    public class AppContext: DbContext
    {
    }
}
```

(To keep it simple, I didn't include anything in the `AppContext` class except the base class.)

When I add a project with the `EntityFrameworkCore` nuget package to the solution above with just this class I get the error indicated above.

Not sure what the cause is? Do I need to somehow load the nuget package into the workspace? If so, how?

Comment: I think that at least the 'using' is a problem. Then the ';' is reached the object is already disposed. It doesn't explain why the dll can not be found though. The using should be used with curly brackets. using(var x = new y()) { some code }.

Comment: @PaulSinnema this is a new feature in, I believe, C# 8.0, where the using is disposed of a the end of the scope. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8#using-declarations

Comment: Dependencies are not loaded automatically. You can preload them without context, preload them into the default load context, or load them by handling the AppDomain.AssemblyResolve event. See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `AssemblyDependencyResolver` and custom `AssemblyLoadContext` (from [System.Runtime.Loader](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Runtime.Loader)) to help load assemblies with dependencies.

Here is the custom `AssemblyLoadContext`, allowing to resolve dependencies:

```cs
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Loader;

namespace TestRoslyn
{
    public class LoadContext : AssemblyLoadContext
    {
        private AssemblyDependencyResolver _resolver;

        public LoadContext(string assemblyPath)
        {
            _resolver = new AssemblyDependencyResolver(assemblyPath);
        }

        protected override Assembly Load(AssemblyName assemblyName)
        {
            string assemblyPath = _resolver.ResolveAssemblyToPath(assemblyName);
            if (assemblyPath != null)
            {
                return LoadFromAssemblyPath(assemblyPath);
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected override IntPtr LoadUnmanagedDll(string unmanagedDllName)
        {
            string libraryPath = _resolver.ResolveUnmanagedDllToPath(unmanagedDllName);
            if (libraryPath != null)
            {
                return LoadUnmanagedDllFromPath(libraryPath);
            }

            return IntPtr.Zero;
        }
    }
}
```

It can be used like this:

```cs
foreach (var p in sln.Projects)
{
    string outputPath = p.OutputFilePath;
    AssemblyName assemblyName = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(outputPath);
    LoadContext loadContext = new LoadContext(outputPath);
    Assembly asm = loadContext.LoadFromAssemblyName(assemblyName);
    
    foreach (var t in asm.GetTypes()) 
        Console.WriteLine($"{p.OutputFilePath}\t{t.FullName}");
}
```

See details [here](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/docs/design/features/assemblyloadcontext.md) and [here](https://github.com/dotnet/samples/tree/main/core/extensions/AppWithPlugin).